# Security Vulnerability in Enabling CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, security

In my project I have one json files, One I deployed in the Local Machine/Server and other I deployed in the another server.

Here is my code for calling the json data from angular controller -

```
function Controller($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/RESTCall/test.json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.lists= data;
        });
}


function Controller2($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://<Server IP>:8080/RESTCall/test.json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.lists= data;
        });
}
```

Here is my index.html page, where I am using both this controller :

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">    
    <ul ng-repeat="list in lists">
        <li>            
        {{list.testdata}}
        </li>
    </ul>     
</div>


<div ng-controller="Controller2">    
    <ul ng-repeat="list in lists">
        <li>            
        {{list.testdata}}
        </li>
    </ul>     
</div>
```

This is working fine when I enabling CORS in the server side under conf/web.xml by following :

```
<filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
```

**Is it safe ? Is there any Security Vulnerability Issue to enabling CORS ?**

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR; It is safe**

If it is static public information you have nothing to worry about unless the bandwidth. Basically any web application can access the static json files anywhere. Even if you dont have this restriction you can still access it via curl if you dont have a authentication method.

If you want to be still restrictive use a domain name other than `*` which will only allow the web requests from that servers websites.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS